# AutoUpdater for Electron application (signed application)

Tags: macos, electron

I have been struggling with setting correct auto-updater for my Electron Application for Mac OS X (for Windows it works properly)

> 1. I generated Developer ID Application and Developer ID Installer from Xcode and export both certificates into single one using KeyChain.
> 2. Set type: "distribution" in package.json
> 3. Runned the following command CSC_LINK=PATH_TO_MY_P12_CERTIFICATE_FILE yarn dist
> 4. All content from ./dist folder copied to the amazon s3 proper place.

Anyway after launching old version of application which properly finds the update on the server, returns the following problem:

> "Code signature at URL ... did not pass validation: code object is not signed at all"

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How did you export both certificates into a single one?

Comment: Also did you specify CSC_KEY_PASSWORD

Comment: Okey, i did it one more time. I obtained certificate (Developer ID application) from apple.developer.com. Then i set CSC_NAME only (without password) i created dmg again. Still unsuccessful.

Comment: what format is the certificate? .cer or .p12

Comment: @Ajey I am using .p12

Comment: okay and are you setting the password for your .p12 file? And also do you mean the error you are getting during the update from old app(not codesigned/different certificate) to new app(code signed with the above steps). Please provide more data or logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, I found the solution. I had multiple dependencies included in the project (golang server, ffmpeg, AppleScript). It was caused by extra dependency (AppleScript). Saving the file again as application (run only, .app extension) fixed the problem.

Here's the link to the ticket on electron-builder page, where i post all steps that i made: [enter link description here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/2399)